# Batch populate JPEG IPTC keyword from csv or txt file

Tags: path, metadata, jpeg, keyword, append

I have 50,000-plus JPG files which I've tagged for easy lookup by user-selected keywords. The database which matches image files with their keywords is proprietary and utility-specific. I want to switch to embedding keywords in each image's IPTC keyword metadata field so that I'm not dependent on any one utility and its database. I can manipulate my current database to yield a CSV or TXT file containing each image's pathname and the keywords assigned to each image. Is there a utility which can batch write multiple IPTC keywords to image files across multiple folders, using a CSV or TXT file as input? IrfanView and Zoner Photo Studio can batch write IPTC keywords, but only in one folder at a time, and neither appears to accept CSV or TXT file input. I'm dealing with several hundred folders and a couple dozen keywords. Photo Mechanic might be able to do it but I'm running Windows XP, and Photo Mechanic for Win XP is no longer available.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't profess to know the exact answer, but I might be able to point you in the right direction. The command-line utility exiftool (http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) may well be able to do what you want.

See https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16305/how-can-i-batch-add-keywords-metadata-to-jpgs-with-matching

In my case I just wanted to find an easier way to caption about 1,500 photos from an overseas trip, using the flexibility of a word processor instead of having to do it one by one in a program like Geosetter.

After renaming the photos, I generated a tab-delimited list of the file names with a blank Description field using this batch file:

==========

rem Dropping a folder on the following .BAT file will create "captions.txt" in the folder:

rem Note that there is a TAB character in the next line between "SourceFile" and "Description"

echo "SourceFile    Description" > %1\captions.txt

C:\exiftool\exiftool -T -filename -description -ext jpg %1 >> %1\captions.txt

==========

Then I opened captions.txt in Word (landscape format works best), set a tab stop/hanging indent for easier readability, and typed the captions as required.

I then loaded the resulting file into Excel, saved as a CSV, then used this batch command to write the captions to the files:

==========

C:\exiftool\exiftool -csv=captions.csv -ext jpg .

pause

==========

Comment: Thank you, @Frank, I will look into exiftool and see if it will do what I need.